# How to make Vim plugin NERDTree's <CR> behave more like `go`?

Tags: vim, mapping, nerdtree

In NERDTree, `<CR>` is same as shortcut `o` which in its help doc is described as below:

```
Default key: o
Map option: NERDTreeMapActivateNode
Applies to: files and directories.

If a file node is selected, it is opened in the previous window.

If a directory is selected it is opened or closed depending on its current
state.

If a bookmark that links to a directory is selected then that directory
becomes the new root.

If a bookmark that links to a file is selected then that file is opened in the
previous window.
```

I want to **open a file with the cursor just remained in the NERDTree**.

I found it's just the action that shortcut `go` does. But `go` can only be applied to `files` while `o` is applied to `files and directories`.

In the NERDTree's help doc:

```
Default key: go
Map option: None
Applies to: files.

If a file node is selected, it is opened in the previous window, but the
cursor does not move.

The key combo for this mapping is always "g" + NERDTreeMapActivateNode (see
NERDTree-o).
```

More specifically, I want `<CR>` to behave as `o` when applied to `directories`, and `go` when `files`.

There is no `Customisation` flag to do that.

Is there any good way to implement it including modifying the source script?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that it can be accomplished using custom mappings which unfortunately cannot be defined usual way in your `.vimrc`. You need to distinguish if the node is a `'FileNode'` or a `'DirNode'` so the mappings must be specified in a file like `~/.vim/nerdtree_plugin/mymappings.vim`.

```
call NERDTreeAddKeyMap({
    \ 'key': '<CR>', 
    \ 'scope': 'DirNode',
    \ 'callback': 'NERDTreeCustomActivateDirNode',
    \ 'quickhelpText': 'open or close a dirctory',
    \ 'override': 1 })

function! NERDTreeCustomActivateDirNode(node)
    call a:node.activate()
endfunction

call NERDTreeAddKeyMap({
    \ 'key': '<CR>',
    \ 'scope': 'FileNode',
    \ 'callback': 'NERDTreeCustomPreviewNodeCurrent',
    \ 'quickhelpText': 'open a file with the cursor in the NERDTree',
    \ 'override': 1 })

function! NERDTreeCustomPreviewNodeCurrent(node)
    call a:node.open({'stay': 1, 'where': 'p', 'keepopen': 1})
endfunction
```

I found the inspiration in [`/autoload/nerdtree/ui_glue.vim`](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/blob/master/autoload/nerdtree/ui_glue.vim).

- More information in [`:h NERDTreeKeymapAPI`](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/blob/master/doc/NERD_tree.txt#L1054).

<sup>(I don't have NERDTree so it is not tested.)</sup>

Comment: exactly what I want. Thanks a lot!